# Using R aggregate function over a dataframe with names

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the form of:

df:

```
RepName, Discount
Bob,Smith , 5383.24
Johh,Doe ,  30349.21
...
```

The names are repeated. In the df, RepName is a factor and Discount is numeric. I want to calculate the mean per RepName. I can't seem to get the aggregate statement right.

I've tried:

```
#This doesn't work
repAggDiscount <- aggregate(repdf,  by = repdf$RepName, FUN = mean)

#Not what I want:
repAggDiscount <- aggregate(repdf,  by = list(repdf$RepName), FUN = mean)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
repnames <- lapply(repdf$RepName, toString)
repAggDiscount <- aggregate(repdf,  by = repnames, FUN = mean)
```

But that gives me a length mismatch...

I've read the help but an example of how this should work for my data would go a long way... thanks!

Comment: Are you open to other packages?

Comment: `aggregate(Discount ~ RepName, repdf, mean)` perhaps?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, that seemed to work. Why did my way not work?

Comment: For big data sets use `data.table` package. i.e., `library(data.table);
setDT(repdf)[, list(Discount = mean(Discount)), by = RepName]`

Comment: Because the syntax isn't quite right. You're aggregating the whole data frame and not just the relevant columns the way you've written things.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, hmm, that helps. Can you provide an example using matrix notation?

Comment: you cannot mix data types in a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting @AnandaMahto's answer here to close out the question. You can use the formula syntax

```
aggregate(Discount ~ RepName, repdf, mean)
```

Or you can use the `by=` syntax

```
repAggDiscount <- aggregate(repdf$Discount, by = list(repdf$RepName), FUN = mean)
```

The problem with your syntax was that you were trying to aggregate the whole data.frame which included the RepName column where taking the `mean` doesn't make sense

You could also to

```
repAggDiscount <- aggregate(repdf[,-1], by = repdf[,1,drop=F], FUN = mean)
```

which is closer to the matrix style syntax.